# How to setup Ansible Fact Collection from Ansible AWX (Ansible Tower Web console)

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

How to setup Ansible Fact Collection and make it collect automatically every 5 min interval from Ansible AWX (Ansible Tower Web console)?

Answer (score 1):

Is your intent to use ansible to collect facts **from** your AWX containers? Or use AWX to gather facts from remote hosts?

For the latter, you can utilize the setup module in a task:

```
- name: Collect facts
  setup:
```

Then within AWX:

1. Create a new [job template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#) to run the playbook containing the setup task.
2. [Schedule](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html#schedule-a-job-template) template execution for every 5 minutes.